# Android SQlite problem

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to update a cell in a row of a data base. But the result always ends up as 0, meaning no changes where made. what am I doing wrong?

The name of the column is "Read" and all values in that column are initially 0. I need to update the value of a row's column "Read" to integer 1.

```
    DATABASE = openOrCreateDatabase("MAIN_DB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Read", new Integer(1));
    int result=0;

    DATABASE.beginTransaction();

        result= DATABASE.update(databasename, contentValues, "id="+db_rowid, null);
        DATABASE.setTransactionSuccessful();

        DATABASE.endTransaction();


    DATABASE.close();
```

The variable db_rowid = the row id of the row i need to edit

Comment: I see no error if databasename = "MAIN_DB", dbcolumnid is a existing value and the columns id and Read exitst in table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `databasename` is actually the table name which contains your row. The `dbcolumnid` is actually the row ID to update. And your table contain the `id` column (is it primary key?). With these assumptions all should work.

Finally, you can try this:

```
result = DATABASE.update(databasename, contentValues, "id=?", new String[] {Long.toString(dbcolumnid)});
```

Comment: yes, I added the "_id" column and then used your code and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read this post about SQLite. I think you can get some good pointers on how to implement it.

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-simple-but-persistent-data-storage/

Comment: thanks, but that post says nothing about updating a cell or even a row.